# python dataframe how to pad to cerain number of rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pad

I have multiple dataframe with number of rows that varies between 8,9,10.
I want to take the dataframe with len 8,9 and add them rows of zeros - to make them with 10 rows also.

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) in list comprehension:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dfs = [x.reindex(range(10), fill_value=0) for x in dfs]
```

If need reindex by maximum index values create maximum length dynamically:

```
m = len(max(dfs, key=len))
dfs = [x.reindex(range(m), fill_value=0) for x in dfs]
```